# bash - Group and append lines to array based on condition

Tags: bash, awk

I'm sure this must be answered somewhere, but I don't quite know how to search for my issue.

I have a file with X number of lines as such:

```
fruit=orange origin=spain seller=walmart amount=10
fruit=banana origin=colombia seller=walmart amount=5
fruit=apple origin=france seller=target amount=3
fruit=orange origin=spain seller=target amount=4
fruit=orange origin=spain seller=walmart amount=4
fruit=apple origin=spain seller=walmart amount=90
```

What I want to do is to loop through these lines, bundle together all lines with the same `fruit` value and calculate the total `amount`. The twist is that I can't tell on beforehand what values there will be in `fruit`.

This is what I've got so far:

```
cat fruits.txt |
    while read data
    do
        for i in "$data"; do
            if [[ some condition]]; then
                echo $i >> fruits2.txt
            fi
        done
    done
```

I realize I have to iterate through each line and save it if the condition is met. But how do I keep the loop going until all lines have been iterated through and the amounts added together?

The output I'm expecting should look like this:

```
   Fruit     Amount 
   orange    18
   apple     93
   etc ...
```

Comment: You are missing the amount in last line

Comment: my mistake, hasn't got anything to do with my actual problem though

Comment: Can you show us how the final output should look like? and can you use `Awk`, it should be pretty easy with that

Comment: Updated with expected output. I'd rather do this as vanilla as possible as I'm trying to learn bash from scratch.

Comment: You missed having a banana ;)

Comment: Then I good lesson for you do take from this to understand, `bash` is not the best language to parse file contents! tools like `Awk`, `perl` are more meant for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty easy with `Awk`, just set a multi-char de-limiter for parsing words in your lines `[= ]` i.e. a `=` sign and a single space, with it done, the `$2` becomes the fruit name and `$NF` becomes the count of fruits. With this set, all you need to do is,

```
awk -F'[= ]' '{fruitCount[$2]+=$NF; next}END{for (fruit in fruitCount) printf "Count of %s is %s\n",fruit,fruitCount[fruit]}' file
```

which produces an output as

```
Count of orange is 18
Count of apple is 93
Count of banana is 5
```

(or) to print in the format, OP wanted,

```
awk -F'[= ]' 'BEGIN{printf "Fruit\tAmount\n"}{fruitCount[$2]+=$NF; next}END{for (fruit in fruitCount) printf "%s\t%s\n",fruit,fruitCount[fruit]}' file
```

should give you,

```
Fruit   Amount
orange  18
apple   93
banana  5
```

---

OP wanted to get the input as the fruit and return the count of that fruit. It should work with a `read` command and importing that in that `Awk` command. In an `bash` script,

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -p "Enter fruit name: " fruitName
awk -F'[= ]' -v fruit="${fruitName}" 'BEGIN{printf "Fruit\tAmount\n"}$2 ~ fruit {fruitCount[$2]+=$NF; next}END{for (fruit in fruitCount) printf "%s\t%s\n",fruit,fruitCount[fruit]}' file
```

and run the script as `bash script.sh`. Some sample results,

```
$ bash script.sh
Enter fruit name: orange
Fruit   Amount
orange  18

$ bash script.sh
Enter fruit name: apple
Fruit   Amount
apple   93

$ bash script.sh
Enter fruit name: banana
Fruit   Amount
banana  5
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I do this but telling awk that it is explicitly the `fruit` and `amount` field that I'm interested in. Thinking I might get other lines inside my file with other fields, or the fields jumbled up.

Comment: @bork: You mean get fruit `Orange` and it should return `18`?